# How to properly create an EF One-to-Zero-or-One relationship with navigation properties on both ends?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my model I have two objects: `Lead` and `Work`. `Lead` *may* have a related `Work`, but `Work` *must* have a related `Lead`. How do I properly express this using EF Code First and Fluent API? I've spent most of the day so far going in circles trying to do this, but I'm getting nowhere. The problem (maybe?), is that I need to have the navigation properties on both sides of the relationship. Here's how I've got my objects configured so far:

```
public class Lead {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? WorkId { get; set; }
    public virtual Work Work { get; set; }
}

public class Work {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //public int LeadId { get; set; } <- I think this is necessary?
    public virtual Lead Lead { get; set; }
}

// this seems to make a one-to-one relationship, but it's setting
// the column references as the Id columns on both sides, so it's wrong...
// Also causes this exception:
// A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'.
this.HasOptional(t => t.Work).WithRequired(t => t.Lead);
```

Attempting to reverse engineer a test database yields a One-to-Many relationship, which is not what I want. I'd appreciate suggestions on how to properly configure the relationship.

Comment: Lead is the principal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If lead is a principal (Lead must exist first), the classes could look like this.

```
public class Lead {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Work Work { get; set; }
}

public class Work {
    [Key, ForeignKey("Lead")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Lead Lead { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way and was very similar to what EF was producing for me, except I thought it was wrong. Either way, after some more pondering, I realized that the `Work` object was actually unnecessary, so I've removed it. But, again, for everyone else looking for a similar solution this is correct.

Comment: This approach is failing for me because my Id properties are identity columns.  EF 6 wouldn't allow me to set create a Foreign Key on an identity column (in my equivalent of the Work entity from your example above)... at least that's what the helpful error message seems to be getting at.